# Let $\mu$ be an integer $\geq2$. What is the Pontryagin Dual of $ \mathbb{Q}/\mu\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, harmonic-analysis

I already know that $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ has $\prod_{p\textrm{ prime}}\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ as its Pontryagin dual, and I'm pretty sure that  $\mathbb{Q}/\mu\mathbb{Z}$ will depend on the prime divisors of $\mu$, but I can't figure it out, nor can I find an answer anywhere else on the internet. Formally, I get that the answer should be $\prod_{p\textrm{ prime}}\mu\mathbb{Z}\left(p^{\infty}\right)$, but I can't find any resource about what manipulations are valid when working with cosets of Prüfer $p$-groups. I'd like the answer, please, so that I can get on with my research. (Note: here, "answer" means *answer*, not "hint", or "patronizing remark about how I should be able to figure it out myself".)

Anyhow, thanks in advance.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}/\mu\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, so it doesn't depend on $\mu$.

Comment: Isn't $\{ (\frac{a}{n}+\Bbb{Z} \mapsto \exp(2i \pi \frac{y_n a\bmod n}{n})), (y_n) \in \hat{\Bbb{Z}}\}$ is the Pontryagin dual of $\Bbb{Q/Z}$ with the discrete topology. With the $\Bbb{R/Z}$ topology the Pontryagin dual is $\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: @user10354138 Let $f:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a function of period $1$ such that $f\left(t+x\right)=f\left(t\right)$ for all$ t\in\mathbb{Q}$ if and only if $x\in\mathbb{Z}$. Let $\mu=3$ and let $g\left(t\right)=f\left(\frac{t}{3}\right)$. Then, $g\left(t\right)$ is well defined on $\mathbb{Q}/3\mathbb{Z}$ but not on $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. How can  $\mathbb{Q}/3\mathbb{Z}$ be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, and yet $g$ fails to be defined on both?

Comment: Similarly, take a look at: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3272186/help-with-change-of-indices-in-sums-indexed-over-mathbbq-mathbbz

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic (as a topological group) to $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{\mu Z}$, the isomorphism is given by multiplication by $\mu$. Thus the pontrjagin dual to $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{\mu Z}$ is $(\lim\limits_{\rightarrow}\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{nZ})\hat{} = \lim\limits_{\leftarrow}(\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{nZ})\hat{} = \prod\limits_{p\textrm{ prime}}\mathbb{Z}_{p}$

Comment: Okay then, suppose you have a function $f\left(t\right):\mathbb{Q}/\mu\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ such that $\sum_{t\in\mathbb{Q}/\mu\mathbb{Z}}\left|f\left(t\right)\right|^{2}<\infty$ If $\mu=1$, then the fourier transform of $f\left(t\right)$ is $\hat{f}\left(\mathfrak{z}\right)=\sum_{t\in\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}}f\left(t\right)e^{2\pi i\left\langle t,\mathfrak{z}\right\rangle }$, where $\left\langle t,\mathfrak{z}\right\rangle$ is the duality bracket and $\mathfrak{z}$ is a profinite integer. What is the analog of this formula for $\hat{f}\left(\mathfrak{z}\right)$ when $\mu\geq2$?